# TypeError: _LoginPage.default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, automation, playwright

Here are the three files I have worked with to get the automation up and running. However, when I ran the test, I got an error.

This is the **fixture.ts** file

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import LoginPage from '../pages/shared/LoginPage';

type pages = {
    loginPage: LoginPage;
}

const testPages = base.extend<pages>({
    loginPage: async({page}, use) => {
        await use(new LoginPage(page));
    }
})

export const test = testPages;
export const expect = testPages.expect;
```

This is the **LoginPage.ts** file

```
import { Page } from '@playwright/test';

export default class LoginPage {

    usernameInput = "//input[@name='username']";
    passwordInput = "//input[@name='password']";
    loginButton = "//button[@name='submit']";

    constructor(public page: Page) {}

    async gotoLoginPage() {
        await this.page.goto('https://xyz-website.com');
    }

    async login(username: string, password: string) {
        await this.page.fill(this.usernameInput, username);
        await this.page.fill(this.passwordInput, password);
        await this.page.click(this.loginButton);
    }
}
```

This is the **login.spec.ts** file

```
import {test} from '../utils/fixtures';

test('Login to the XYZ website', async ({loginPage}) => {
    loginPage.gotoLoginPage();
    loginPage.login('hahaha', '123');
})
```

Ran the code `npx playwright test login.spec.ts --headed --project chromium` and got an error

```
TypeError: _LoginPage.default is not a constructor

       at ..\utils\fixtures.ts:10

       8 | const testPages = base.extend<pages>({
       9 |     loginPage: async({page}, use) => {
    > 10 |         await use(new LoginPage(page));
         |                   ^
      11 |     }
      12 | })
```

Answer (score 0):

Playwright does not mention a POM as default class. Please stick to the guidelines

[Fixture](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-fixtures)

[Page object model](https://playwright.dev/docs/pom)

[Global setup of playwrights config 1](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown)

[Global setup of playwrights config 2](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration)

fixture.ts

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import LoginPage from '../pages/shared/LoginPage';

export const test = base.extend<{loginPage: LoginPage}>({
    loginPage: async({page}, use) => {
        const loginPage = new LoginPage(page)
        await loginPage.gotoLoginPage()
        await use(loginPage);
    }
})
export {expect} from '@playwright/test';
```

**LoginPage.ts**

```
//Page Object Model: https://playwright.dev/docs/pom
import {Locator, Page} from '@playwright/test';

export class LoginPage {
    readonly page: Page
    readonly usernameInput: Locator
    readonly passwordInput: Locator
    readonly loginButton: Locator

    constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page // you can move `page` to a superclass and let it inherit. call `super(page)` to reduce overhead
        //Pls use locators instead of css selectors https://playwright.dev/docs/locators
        //disadvantage of css https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath
        this.usernameInput = this.page.getByLabel('username')
        this.passwordInput = this.page.getByLabel('password')
        this.loginButton = this.page.getByRole('button', {name: 'submit'})
    }

    async gotoLoginPage() {
        await this.page.goto('https://xyz-website.com');
    }

    async login(username: string, password: string) {
        await this.usernameInput.fill(username)
        await this.passwordInput.fill(password);
        await this.loginButton.click()
    }
}
```

test.spec.ts

```
import {test} from '../utils/fixtures';

test.describe('Test execution of', () => {
    test('LoginPage', async ({loginPage}) => {
        //whenever you add loginPage as a parameter, .gotoLoginPage() will be invoked automatically because it is part of the fixture. 
        //You can move your base url to your `playwright.config.ts` as well to reduce your overhead --> https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration#basic-configuration
        await loginPage.login('my_username', 'my_password')
    })
```